# Xcode's 4.3.2 Organizer freezes whenever I click the "Archives" tab

Tags: xcode, archive, organizer

I tried to archive a project in order to upload it to TestFlight.
However, when I opened Organizer to export my archive as an ipa, it froze as soon as I clicked the "Archives" tab.

I tried to create another user, same problem.

I tried to remove the content of the archives folder, same as well.

Xcode is now completely unresponsive, and Activity Monitor show a "bash" process taking about 40% of processor.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I can kill it as many times I want, it keeps coming back. The only way to get rid of it is to kill the Xcode process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the answer to the problem!

From terminal execute this 
xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

Found on this other post

[Why does xcode 4.3.2 hang when archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115551/why-does-xcode-4-3-2-hang-when-archiving)

Comment: I still have no idea why does it work, but it does, which is all that matters. You'd think that Apple could have fixed it from 4.3.2 to 4.5...
Anyway - Thanks for the fix :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all try out this: [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/696717). For me it helped once. Also if you run System monitor application while Xcode is hanging, you'll see several bash processes taking all your CPU time. Try to kill them until organizer opens.

If this won't help you either, migrate to Android or Windows Phone. Both Visual Studio and Eclipse are much more friendly :)

Comment: I tried the tricks of that other topic you gave me, it didn't work (or at least it wasn't enough). Then I tried to repeatedly kill the bash processes and it worked :) Thanks a lot

Comment: update:  i had found awhile ago that if you delete the "archives" that you have that were copied over from the old version of Xcode,  this will remove the problem.   (and it is possible that one of the deletes will give you the lock up and you will have to crush the process yet again,  until all old archives are deleted)