# Xcode 5 hangs while archiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5, archiving

I recently converted my iOS project to ARC. Now when I try to archive my app, the process hangs when/after compiling the last source file. 
In Activity Monitor two clang processes are almost on 100% CPU and I can't even switch off Xcode.
If I set the Code Optimization Level to None everything works fine (which of course isn't a final solution).

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling a fresh, clean, blank project just to see if that works?  If that doesn't work, it may not be project related.

Comment: if I compile the project on an old branch (without ARC) everything works fine.

Comment: Sledge hammer :-) I have had this happen to me before and it is really annoying. I just shut the Mac down and went home for the night when I came in the next day it worked fine. My guess would be that it was just having a bad day and overheating or too many processes running and it just couldn't handle it.

Comment: Archiving on a different Mac doesn't work either :-(

Comment: Have you validated your project settings?  Reference the "Project Modernization" section here: [What’s New in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004635-SW1)

Comment: Did you try the sledge hammer? :-P

Comment: @SlyRaskal Yes, Xcode says "Project Settings are valid"

Comment: Do you have any symbolic links? Reference: [XCode hangs when archiving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116934/xcode-hangs-when-archiving)

Comment: Also, have you tried cleaning your project before building?

Comment: I cleaned it and tested it on a newly installed Mac (so no symbolic links) - Thanks for your help by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a retain circle in an animation block in ARC. Using `weakSelf` did the trick.

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.5f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                     [strongSelf doStuff];
                     // ...
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // ...
                 }];
```

I figured this out by archiving the project via command line in verbos mode. It got stuck on one view controller which contained the retain circle.